# Correct way to add a column of random numbers to a dask dataframe

Tags: python, random, dask, random-seed, dask-dataframe

What is the correct way of adding a column of random numbers to a dask dataframe? I could obviously use `map_partitions` to add the column to each partition but I'm not sure how the random state is handled when dask parallelises that computation. (I.e. will it use the same random state in all workers and therefore generate the same random numbers in each worker?)

There seem to be relevant functions in `dask.array.random` (https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/_modules/dask/array/random.html) but I wasn't able to find an example for how to use these together with a dask dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for this question. This is not easy to figure out what with chunk sizes versus partition sizes being so confusing.

Answer (score 3):

According to this discussion
(https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2558), there's no effort to set/track `numpy` seed, and the recommended approach is to use `dask.array` (which was mentioned in the question). Perhaps then the optimal route for reproducible randomness is to create `dask.array` and convert to `dask.dataframe`:

```py
import dask.array as da

# this is not reproducible
for _ in range(3):
    x = da.random.random((10, 1), chunks=(2, 2))
    print(x.sum().compute())

# this is reproducible
for _ in range(3):
    state = da.random.RandomState(1234)
    y = state.random(size=(10,1), chunks=(2,2))
    print(y.sum().compute())

# conver to ddf
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_dask_array(y, columns=['A'])

# if there's another existing dataframe ddf2
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=['B']), npartitions=2)
ddf2

# then simple column assignment will work even if partitions are not aligned
ddf2['A'] = ddf['A']
print((ddf.compute() == ddf2[['A']].compute()).sum() == len(ddf))

# of course it will be more efficient to have partitions align
# you can inspect the DAG with ddf2.visualize() to see why
# also note carefully that the lengths of ddf and ddf2 should match
# otherwise there might be unexpected situations downstream
# to see why, try changing the size of `y` above and then compare
# ddf and ddf2
```

Comment: Thanks for the example with `dask.array`. Considering that I want to add the array as a new column to an existing dask dataframe, is there anything I should do with the `chunks` argument? I.e. how does the chunking of the array and the partitioning of the dataframe relate to each other? Can I create the array in such a way that it is partitioned in the same way as the existing dataframe?

Comment: AFAIK, if your existing dataframe is indexed (`.known_divisions` is True), then a simple assignment will work: `ddf_existing['new_col'] = ddf_from_array['existing_col']` (even if the partition sizes are not aligned). If the divisions are not known, it's trickier. However, maybe this is overcomplicating the situation for your desired use case? Do you need reproducible/controlled randomness? If no, then the `map_partitions` way that you outlined is fine, if you do need, then I guess you will need to make sure that your existing dataframe is indexed (if it's not).

Comment: just added a simple example to the answer above