# Using numpy default_rng with Dask?

Tags: python, numpy, random, dask

I'd like to know how I can use a numpy default random number generator with Dask.

The documentation for e.g. [`dask.array.random.normal`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.array.random.normal.html#dask.array.random.normal) has a note saying :

> New code should use the normal method of a default_rng() instance
> instead

I assume that is because the documentation is copied from numpy.
In numpy they introduced a [default random number generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) so that one can have rngs with different seeds (in contrast to the old global numpy.random.seed) but I can't figure out how to use one with the Dask random functions.

Comment: Not sure this helps in your case, but could you use separate `RandomState` instances? See example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66124973/10693596

Comment: Thanks. From the docs "RandomState provides access to legacy generators. This generator is considered frozen and will have no further improvements." That was the reason for me to ask the question in the first place.
Currently I use numpy to generate random numbers (they have special requirements, not just being random) in batches and later read them from dask. I was just wondering if there is a straight forward way to do it.

Comment: Any update since August?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8790#issue-1162888730) in Dask for a feature request on this specific topic, where you can check if there are any updates.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31242089)